# React UseRef is undefined using a wrapper

Tags: reactjs

I'm following [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-water-pzylr?file=/src/App.js) in order to achive dynamically-created elements that can be printed using react To Print.

I have the following code *(showing sections to keep this question as clean as possible)*:

```
/*This section is loaded after a user has been selected from a select input*/
{rows?.map((row,index) => (
    <PrintHojaVacaciones key={index} vacacion={row}/>
))}
```

---

```
const PrintHojaVacaciones = ({vacacion}) => {
    const componentRef = useRef();
        return (
            <div>
            {vacacion.id} 
            <ReactToPrint
            trigger={() => {
                <SqIconButton tip={`Imprimir (Aprobada por ${vacacion.aprobadapor})`} 
                color={"success"}
                disableElevation={true}>
                <><BsIcons.BsHandThumbsUpFill/><AiIcons.AiFillPrinter/></>
                </SqIconButton>
            }}
            content={() => componentRef.current}
            />
            <Diseno_PrintHojaVacaciones ref={componentRef} value={vacacion}/>
          </div>
       )
}
export default PrintHojaVacaciones
```

---

```
const Diseno_PrintHojaVacaciones = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {
  const { value } = props;
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>{value.aprobadapor}</div>
  );
});

export default Diseno_PrintHojaVacaciones;
```

Thing is, `useRef` is undefined. I have been trying with `CreateRef` as well, with the same result. I also tried to "move" my code to the codesandbox above displayed and it works well, but in my own application, it returns undefined. The whole `useRef` is new to me and I don't understand it well yet, so any help would be appreciated.
The route is being called using Lazy loading from react router (I don't know if this could be the culprit)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what I did to make it work, I really have no idea, but my Trigger now looks like this and it is now working (not sure if I'm missing something else). The difference is that the function is not inside brackets after the `=>`.

```
trigger={() => 
    <SqIconButton tip={`Imprimir (Aprobada por ${vacacion.aprobadapor})`} 
        color={"success"}
        disableElevation={true}>
        <><BsIcons.BsHandThumbsUpFill/><AiIcons.AiFillPrinter/></>
    </SqIconButton>
}
```